# not able to add attachment to the java mail api

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am trying to send txt file as an attachment using java mail api.
    Code is

```
         PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
         out.println("Hiii from doget");
         String[] toAddress = {"abc@gmail.com"};

         boolean debug = false;


         String smtpServer = "smtp.srahosting.com";

         // Set the host smtp address
         Properties props = new Properties();
         props.put( "mail.smtp.host", smtpServer );
         props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "false"); 
         props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

         // create some properties and get the default Session
         Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
         session.setDebug(debug);

         // create a message
         MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
         InternetAddress addressFrom;
        try {
            addressFrom = new InternetAddress("xyz@gmail.com");
            msg.setFrom(addressFrom);
         InternetAddress[] addressTo = new InternetAddress[toAddress.length];
         for (int i = 0; i < toAddress.length; i++) {
                        addressTo[i] = new InternetAddress( toAddress[i] );
         } // for
         msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, addressTo);

         msg.addHeader( "MyHeaderName", "myHeaderValue" );
         msg.setSubject("This is the Subject Line!");
        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        messageBodyPart.setText("This is message body");
         Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
         multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart); 
         MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart2 = new MimeBodyPart();
         File filename = new File(request.getRealPath("/Test.java"));
         DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
         messageBodyPart2.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
      //   messageBodyPart2.setFileName("Ammu");
         Multipart multipart2 = new MimeMultipart();
         multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart2);
         msg.setContent(multipart);
         try{
         Transport.send( msg );}
         catch(Exception e){
             e.printStackTrace();
             out.println("In exception "+"***"+e.getClass().getName());
             for (StackTraceElement ste : Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()) {
                 out.println(ste);
              }
         }
         logThis("msg sent ");
            String title = "Send Email";
         String res = "Sent message successfully....";
         String docType =
         "<!doctype html public \"-//w3c//dtd html 4.0 " +
         "transitional//en\">\n";
         out.println(docType +
         "<html>\n" +
         "<head><title>" + title + "</title></head>\n" +
         "<body bgcolor=\"#f0f0f0\">\n" +
         "<h1 align=\"center\">" + title + "</h1>\n" +
         "<p align=\"center\">" + res + "</p>\n" +
         "</body></html>"); 
         }
        catch (MessagingException mex){
            logThis("In exception block");
            mex.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
```

It is working fine without attachment. When I am adding attachment it giving these error

```
**
VM.doGet(VaersMail.java:98)
VM.doPost(VaersMail.java:30)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProcessor.process(AjpAprProcessor.java:188)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2522)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2511)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Th`enter code here`read.run(Thread.java:745)**
```

Can anyone help.I tried many codes from net. I am using servlets. Auth = false , port number added. Before that changes also code is not working. If I comment

```
     Multipart multipart2 = new MimeMultipart();
     multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart2);
```

its working fine.
If there is any problem with Auth or port it should work without attachment also right?

Comment: multipart2 is never used, you can remove it.  Are you sure you can read the file represented by "filename"?  Try creating a FileInputStream for that file and see if you can read it yourself before sending the message.  Maybe the file doesn't exist or you don't have permission to read it?  Also, turn on [JavaMail debugging](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) in case the debug output will provide more clues.

Comment: Hi  @BillShannon , like you said I tried reading that file. Its throwing exactly the same exception stack. What does that mean. Can i do some thing from my end to get the permissions or should I contact sysadmin

Comment: Are you sure the file you're trying to access actually exists on the server?  Who created the file?  If someone else created it, why do you think you should have permission to access it?  You need to think through these permission issues to find the right solution based on what your program is trying to do.  Presumably it's not just trying to send one file once, so you'll need to understand how to solve this problem for future cases as well.